# How to find bounds of a google.maps.FusionTablesLayer?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

I'm building a dynamic Google map of school districts that is powered by a Google Fusion Table. I want users to be able to maniuplate a  list and choose a district for the map to zoom in on.

The markers are rendered in a FusionTablesLayer: 'layer0'.

```
layer0 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    query: {
        select: 'SCHL_FULL_ADDR',
        from: '5119944',
        where: 'CTYDIST = ' + shapes[muni]
    }
});
```

I want to make the map actually zoom in on the school district, so that the district fills the map canvas.

But  I can't figure out how to get the bounds of all the markers on this FusionTablesLayer. There doesn't seem to be anything in the FusionTables api to quickly grab this info.

Can anyone suggest something?

Comment: It does appear right now there is no automatic viewport-type setting for fusiontableslayer like there are in a KMLlayer.  There is a stackoverflow post that gives you geocodezip's solution below -- which is a pull from the Google code examples.  You have to pull that geometry data with Gviz along with calling the fusiontableslayer object.

Answer (score 2):

There are two options I know of:

1. Use [GViz](http://www.geocodezip.com/www_vciregionmap_comC.html) or the Fusion Tables v1 API to query the table for the locations of all the markers in a district, add them to a LatLngBounds object and call map.fitBounds with that bounds. [[another example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_FusionTablesLayer_centerOnMarkers.html)]
2. Add the appropriate center and zoom or bounds to the table (or another table) and use that.

Comment: The problem with the first option is that you need to know the field (or fields) that the FusionTable is using for position. Some of them will have a lat lon pair, while other could have a geojson point in a single geometry field.

Comment: With a FusionTable you always have to adjust the code for the details of the table.

Comment: That would be common sense, yes. But you can actually figure out a bit about the table using Fusion Tables v1 API, on the tables endpoint. I was playing with Derek Eder Fusiontable template and made an experiment . It sorta works.